# emotion css prop styles not applied when using vite

Tags: reactjs, vite, emotion

vite@3.1.6
@vitejs/plugin-react@2.1.6
@emotion/react@11.10.4
react@17.0.2

My vite config

```
{
plugins: [
    react({
        exclude: /\.stories\.(t|j)sx?$/,
        babel: {
            plugins: ["@emotion/babel-plugin"]
        }
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin()
],
esbuild: {
    logOverride: { "this-is-undefined-in-esm": "silent" },
    jsxFactory: `jsx`,
    jsxImportSource: "@emotion/react",
},
build: {
    outDir: "build",
},
server: {
    port: 3000,
},
optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
        define: {
            // Node.js global to browser globalThis
            global: "globalThis",
        },
        plugins: [
            // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
            NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                buffer: true,
            }),
        ],
    },
},
resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true,
    dedupe: ["react", "react-dom", "@emotion/styled", "@emotion/core"],
    alias: [
        {
            // this is required for the scss modules
            find: /^~(.*)$/,
            replacement: '$1',
        },
        {
            find: "@emotion/core",
            replacement: getRootPackageDir("@emotion/react"),
        },
        {
            find: "emotion-theming",
            replacement: getRootPackageDir("@emotion/react"),
        },
        {
            find: "@emotion/styled",
            replacement: getRootPackageDir("@emotion/styled"),
        },
    ],
}
```

}

the css prop styles do not seem to be applied to any component any more.
since I have multiple versions of emotion (10 in dependencies, and 11 in the project itself) i am aliasing everything to my root depedencies

Answer (score 0):

Following this [article](https://dev.to/glocore/configure-emotion-with-your-vite-react-project-7jl), seems like your config should changed from this

```
plugins: [
    react({
        exclude: /\.stories\.(t|j)sx?$/,
        babel: {
            plugins: ["@emotion/babel-plugin"]
        }
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin()
],
```

To this

```
lugins: [
    react({
        exclude: /\.stories\.(t|j)sx?$/,
        jsxImportSource: "@emotion/react",
        babel: {
            plugins: ["@emotion/babel-plugin"]
        }
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin()
],
```

Instead of being part of the `esbuild` configuration

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. You need to do two things:

1. Add `"jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",` to your `tsconfig.json` compilerOption

See snippet below:

```js
tsconfig.json

 "compilerOptions": {
"target": "ES2020",
"useDefineForClassFields": true,
"lib": [
  "ES2020",
  "DOM",
  "DOM.Iterable"
],
"module": "ESNext",
"skipLibCheck": true,
/* Bundler mode */
"moduleResolution": "bundler",
"allowImportingTsExtensions": false,
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"noEmit": true,
"jsx": "react-jsx",
"jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react", // add this line
  },
```

2. Edit your vite.config react plugin to this:

`plugins: [react({ jsxImportSource: "@emotion/react" })],`

See mine below:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react({ jsxImportSource: "@emotion/react" })], // edit to this
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: "@", replacement: "/src" }],
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 3000,
  },
});
```

That's all. The emotion css props should work now!

Comment: You should also be on the latest version of vitejs. At this time, I'm running "vite": "^4.4.5"